# Bootstrap griding system ideas

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Is there any way that i achieve this design but still using the bootstrap griding system?

[image]

I want to make that design. In the sides of the div there should be an accordion like div so that i can click to close the div. I tried using col-md-5 but the grid is to much space just for side panel like. I just want a small div in right side and left side.

Comment: How about changing the 12 grid columns to 14? [grid-system](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about putting the text `<div>` inside the `<div class="col-md-6">`

It would be something like this :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <!-- text -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-11 col-md-1">
                    <!-- text -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy from that answer of yours makes me an idea. Anyway ill make it the correct answer :) thank you